# Unable to get the proper responsive of website on different resolutions using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i have developed the website using bootstrap. i am getting the proper response in mobile and desktop resloutions and unable to get the proper response in remaining devices.

```
            <div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div style="background-color: #3487C2; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">

                        <div style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; color: #ffffff; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 36px; font-weight: 500; padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">
                            <span class="services">Our Services</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 5px;">

                            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 100px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">

                                    <div style="text-align: center;" class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                        <div style="margin: 5px 5px;" class="col-sm-5 left animated fadeInLeft wow">
                                            <a href="HealthSummary.aspx" class="ServiceClick" id="HealthSummary">
                                                <div style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 25px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                                                    <h1  style="color: #3487C2; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Wellness score or Health summary</h1>
                                                    <span style="color: #3487C2; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It's easy
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="margin: 5px 5px;" class="col-sm-5 right animated fadeInRight wow">
                                            <a href="HistoricalRecords.aspx" class="ServiceClick" id="HistoricalRecords">
                                                <div style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 25px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                                                    <h1 style="color: #3487C2; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Historical records storing</h1>
                                                    <span style="color: #3487C2; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It's easy
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div style="text-align: center;" class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                        <div style="margin: 5px 5px;" class="col-sm-5 left animated fadeInLeft wow">
                                            <a href="ExpertOpinon.aspx" class="ServiceClick" id="ExpertOpinon">
                                                <div style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 14px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                                                    <h1 style="color: #3487C2; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Sharing the data or expert opinion
                                                        <br />
                                                        (Doctors, Family members, etc..)</h1>
                                                    <span style="color: #3487C2; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It's easy
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="margin: 5px 5px;" class="col-sm-5 right animated fadeInRight wow">
                                            <a href="EmergencyContact.aspx" class="ServiceClick" id="EmergencyContact">
                                                <div style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 25px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                                                    <h1 style="color: #3487C2; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Emergency contact info</h1>
                                                    <span style="color: #3487C2; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It's easy
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div style="text-align: center;" class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                        <div style="margin: 5px 5px;" class="col-sm-5 left animated fadeInLeft wow">
                                            <a href="Security.aspx" class="ServiceClick" id="Security">
                                                <div style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 25px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                                                    <h1 style="color: #3487C2; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Security</h1>
                                                    <span style="color: #3487C2; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It's easy
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="margin: 5px 5px;" class="col-sm-5 right animated fadeInRight wow">
                                            <a href="Recommendations.aspx" class="ServiceClick" id="Recommendations">
                                                <div style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 25px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                                                    <h1 style="color: #3487C2; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Recommendations</h1>
                                                    <span style="color: #3487C2; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It's easy
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>

            </div>


 here is my  error screenshot image
```

http://www.imagehousing.com/image/beauty/1279723

Comment: link to image not working

Comment: hi @HeinrichHenning, now it is working can  u find that.

Comment: And how do you want your end result to look? ( My guess is the space between the top/bottom of your boxes is bothering you, which you can fix by giving your boxes a fixed height. ) Maybe create a JSFiddle with your current code, and add an image of the end result you want (define for us what you mean by proper response).

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: hi @GermanoPlebani, i am getting the big size and small size boxes  during different resolution on different browsers.

Comment: Unlikely the bootstrap coloumn don't have the same height. Here you can find a method to do so http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

Comment: hi @HeinrichHenning, here is my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/1WNj7bl5fqCYu30UKYlf?p=preview, i want boxes with same height during different resolutions common to all browser

Comment: hi @GermanoPlebani, here is my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/1WNj7bl5fqCYu30UKYlf?p=preview, i want boxes with same height during different resolutions common to all browser